# Inserting backslash into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
    VALUES ('$name', 'img\\" . $image['name'] . "', '$category')
```

it is for uploading an image, and I need to upload the image location hence needing
img\imagename.jpg

I am struggling with how to insert the backslash for the img\ as one leads to an error and double enters none into the database for some reason.

Thank you

Comment: Use 4 backslashes. once escape for mysql, once for php.

Comment: @user2268032, You should never be escaping things manually.  Ever.  See my answer for the proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared/parameterized queries.  Then you don't have to worry about escaping data yourself, and are protected from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you should have:

```
VALUES (:name, :img_name, :category)
```

Then, [using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you can bind your values to each insertion point in your query to be sure things are properly escaped.